# I added PATHs to ~/.bashrc and /root/.bashrc, but "sudo adb" still reports "command not found"?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I added `PATH`s to `~/.bashrc` and `/root/.bashrc`, but `sudo adb` still reports "command not found"?

I rebooted as well.

So I need a way to get `sudo`'s `.bashrc` to be synced with my user's `.bashrc`?

The paths are right as I can run from my user, just not sudo:

```
PATH=~/android-sdks/tools:$PATH
PATH=~/android-sdks/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Comment: check +x permissions on adb. Do `which adb` to see whether/where it finds it

Comment: I suggest trying _full complete paths_ in your `PATH` variable; I just don't trust `~` expansion to work 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright I just modified to script to replace every occurrence of sudo adb with sudo ~/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb thats good enough

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I got it:

```
sudo -E adb
```

man sudo:

```
   -E          The -E (preserve environment) option will override the env_reset option in
               sudoers(5)).  It is only available when either the matching command has the SETENV
               tag or the setenv option is set in sudoers(5).
```

Comment: Most likely won't work because of the secure_path set in sudoers file. It should work for other environment variables, just not PATH.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure you have an `export PATH` after in your bashrc after you modify PATH?

i.e.

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/userfoo/dir/android-sdks/platform-tools:/path/to/userfoo/android-sdks/tools
export PATH
```

Try sudo with the above settings and see how far you get.  If no dice then:

It may very well be that you have secure_path set in your shudders file and that may be cramping your style; for more details:

```
man 5 sudoers
```

Make sure that in your /etc/sudoers for your user you have the `SETENV` option set: for example:

```
userfoo ALL=(ALL) SETENV: ALL
```

Give it a go...

Comment: thanks tried both, is it important to place userfoo ALL=(ALL) SETENV: ALL at the top or bottom? edit nvmd tried both top and bottom didn't work.